# software to decide whether a 2-generator subgroup of PSL(2,R) is discrete/free

Tags: reference-request, algorithms, hyperbolic-geometry, free-groups

Gilman developed an algorithm with polynomial complexity that, given two elements in PSL(2,R), decides whether the group they generate is free/discrete or not. I was wondering whether anybody ever tried to implement this algorithm or an equivalent one to produce a piece of software that can answer to this question.

Thank you,
regards.